# Dynamic column selection as per user input in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm showing the user a screen where he can check what fields he wants to get from the database. Based on the checked checkboxes I want to write a query using LINQ or lambda expression and fetch the data in ASP.NET MVC. How to do that as column selections are dynamic? For example, if only Name and Email columns are checked then get the data of those 2 columns only from the database.

> Controller

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(Employee emp)
{
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    employees = db.Employees.Select(x => new Employee()
                {
                    // select Only those columns which are checked by the user
                }).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

> View

```html
@model IEnumerable<DynamicCheck.Models.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeReport";
}

<h2>EmployeeReport</h2>

<form action="~/Employees/Report" method="post">
    <div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="Name" />
            <label>Employee Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="Email" />
            <label>Employee Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="Address" />
            <label>Employee Address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="Phone" />
            <label>Employee Name</label>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should to use javascript and check what columns sent to view.
and create html elements dynamically...